# File I/O Java Program not recognizing my .txt file in the src folder

Tags: java, file-io, filenotfoundexception

I have the following program, and the file "euler8.txt" stored in the project's src folder `C:\Users\john\workspace\Euler1\src\euler8.txt`. I am getting the exception `Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: euler8.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)` when I try to run.

```
private static void euler8() throws IOException
{   
    int current;
    int largest=0;
    int c =0;
    ArrayList<Integer> bar = new ArrayList<Integer>(0);
    File infile = new File("C:/Users/xxxxxxxx/workspace/Euler1/euler8.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
            new FileInputStream(infile),
            Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    try
    {
        while((c = reader.read()) != -1) 
        {
            bar.add(c);
        }
    }
    finally{reader.close();}
    for(int i=0; i<bar.size(); i++)
    {
        current = bar.get(i) * bar.get(i+1) * bar.get(i+2) * bar.get(i+3) * bar.get(i+4);
        if(largest<current)
            largest = current;
    }
}
```

Image of what I'm looking at now
http://img163.imageshack.us/img163/7017/halpbk.png

Comment: `File infile = new File("C:\Users\john\workspace\Euler1\src\euler8.txt");` Give absolute path

Comment: or put the file in `C:\Users\john\workspace\Euler1\ `

Comment: Check whether this file is present on the on the classes (or similar) folder (where your classes are stored after compilation)

Comment: @jlordo did that, did not work. I'll just put literal path, however I don't know why what you suggested is not working.

Comment: Tried literal path, however since the path contains \ it thinks I'm trying to do escape sequences. using ' instead of " didn't work either, and is producing the error `invalid character constant`

Comment: @JamesRoberts you need to escape the backslashes like this: `"C:\\Path\\to\\file"`

Answer (score 1):

You should either move your text file out of your `src` folder, to place it directly under the project folder.

---

**Or,** for your current location, change the path to: -

```
File infile = new File("./src/euler8.txt");
```

The path you give is relative to the root folder, and hence it cannot find the file if you give `"euler8.txt"`. You need to give path relative to the project folder to go into the `src` folder.

You can also give `absolute path`, but it is not the way to go, as it calls for the modification of path every time you move your project to a different location.

Answer (score 1):

This line looking for your text file in root folder.

```
       File infile = new File("euler8.txt");
```

You need to give absolute path like this

```
      File infile = new File("C:/Users/john/workspace/Euler1/src/euler8.txt");
```

OR as jLordo suggested move your file to your root folder

Comment: You need to give `forward-slash` in your path. Or, double back-slashes.

Answer (score 1):

Three solutions. choose one:

1: move euler.txt from src one directory up
2: change line to

```
File infile = new File("./src/euler8.txt");
```

3: use absolute path

```
String path  = "C:/Users/john/workspace/Euler1/src/";
String file = "euler8.txt";
File infile = new File(path + file);
```

Comment: Strange, Solution 3 must ever work. Are you sure the file exists? C:/Users can also be critical because of Windows. Open a command line window and change to that dir, and Look if the path has the correct Name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("euler8.txt");
        String sa = "";
        int cc;
        while((cc = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
            sa += (char) cc;
        }
```

assumes that euler8.txt is in src folder

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, the current working directory is the directory from which the program was launched, not the src directory.  You can always find the current working directory with

```
String workingDir = new java.io.File( "." ).getCanonicalPath();
```